# capture day in calfw calendar and pass it to org-agenda

Tags: org-mode, calendar, calfw

I am trying to capture from the calfw calendar and have the entry appear in the agenda buffer, in the same way that the emacs calendar does.
with bind c for capture it tells me that there is no cfw:org-capture-template set.

my code:

```
    (require 'calfw)
(use-package calfw
    :config
  (setq cfw:org-overwrite-default-keybinding t)) ;; atajos de teclado de la agenda org-mode

(use-package calfw-org
    :ensure t
    :config
    (setq cfw:org-overwrite-default-keybinding t))
    :bind ([f5] . cfw:open-org-calendar))
```

In org-calfw file say this:

```
(defcustom cfw:org-capture-template nil
  "org-capture template. If you use `org-capture' with `calfw', you shold set like
'(\"c\" \"calfw2org\" entry (file nil)  \"* %?\n %(cfw:org-capture-day)\")"
  :group 'cfw-org
  :version "24.1"
  :type
  '(list string string symbol (list symbol (choice file (const nil))) string))
```

somebody know how do this?